# errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date

Tags: database, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, operators

I'm trying to aggregate the sum of sales by month and year for a given year.  So I follow the documentation and what others have done with this code:

```
`db.sales.aggregate([{$project: {year: {$year: "saleDate"}, month: {$month: "saleDate"}, dayOfMonth: 
                    {$dayOfMonth: "saleDate"}}}, {$group: {_id: {year: '$year', month: '$month'}, 
                     count: {$sum: 1}}}]);
```

But it returns the error: 
    `"errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date"`

I dont understand why when the schema in Compass says its a "date" type.

I try a different way I've seen done using 'new Date' function but I get no error but no results..  I can't figure out how to work with dates in mongo

```
`db.sales.aggregate([{$match: {'saleDate': {$gte: {$dayOfYear: new Date("2017-06-01")}, 
                      $lt: {$dayOfYear: new Date("2017-07-01")}}}}, 
                      {$group: {_id: { 'numberofSales': {$sum: 1}}}}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first query is that you're missing the dollar sign and MongoDB considers `saleDate` as hardcoded **string** as opposed to `$saleDate` which will be considered as a **field reference**, try:

```
db.sales.aggregate([{$project: {year: {$year: "$saleDate"}, month: {$month: "$saleDate"}, dayOfMonth: 
                    {$dayOfMonth: "$saleDate"}}}, {$group: {_id: {year: '$year', month: '$month'}, 
                    count: {$sum: 1}}}]);
```

More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables)

Your second query won't work because you're trying to compare a number returned by [$dayOfYear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/index.html) against date field.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.  I'm still having trouble with those dollar signs.  When to use them and when not to when you are referencing field names.  Sometimes It throws me an error saying not to, but in this case you do!  But I dont understand why that wouldntnt be the error message and not, "Cant convert BSON type to date" when "saleDate" is obviously a date type

Comment: @BenSmith generally, you shoulldn't use the in `find` statements and `$match`. Every other pipeline stage interprets a string without a dollar sign as "fixed" value. If you have any case please post your query with sample documents into mongoplayground.net - I will try to take a look later